# Making a loop in the processing

Tags: java, processing

I was working on an animation on processing. Then, I have a question about the loop. Normally, my code is more long. However, I made a simple code which can usefull also for the beginners.
My sample code:

```
void setup() 
{  
  size(500, 500);

  coordinates = loadStrings("coordinates.txt");
  beginShape();         // It combines the all of vertexes
}

void draw() 
{
  point(initialX, initialY);
  println(initialX, initialY, p);

}
```

How to I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that you need to fix your `setup` method to get the points data from the line and then modify `draw` method to use these points in a loop:

```
int[][] points;
int curr = 0;

void setup() {

    size(500, 500);

    strokeWeight(4);
    frameRate(5);

    coordinates = loadStrings("coordinates.txt");
    beginShape();         // It combines the all of vertexes

    points = new int[coordinates.length][2];
    int row = 0;
    for (String line : coordinates) {
        String[] pair = line.split(" ");
        points[row] = new int[] { Integer.parseInt(pair[0]), Integer.parseInt(pair[1])};
        println(points[row][0]); // print x
        println(points[row][1]); // print y
        row++;
    }

    fixLineCoords();
    endShape(CLOSE);
}

void fixLineCoords() {
    int indexStart = curr % points.length;
    int indexEnd = (curr + 1) % points.length;
    initialX = points[indexStart][0];
    initialY = points[indexStart][1];
    finalX = points[indexEnd][0];
    finalY = points[indexEnd][1];

    deltaX = abs(finalX - initialX);
    deltaY = abs(finalY - initialY);
    p = 2 * deltaY - deltaX;

    println("Line between points " + curr + " and " + (curr+1));
    counter = 0; // reset counter;
}

void draw() {
    point(initialX, initialY);
    println(initialX, initialY, p);

    if (finalX > initialX )
        initialX++;
    else
        initialX--;

    if (p < 0) {
        p = p + 2 * deltaY;
    } else {
        if (initialY > finalY)
            initialY--;
        else
            initialY++;
        p = p + 2 * deltaY - 2 * deltaX;
    }

    counter++;
    if (counter > deltaX) {
        if (curr == points.length) {
            noLoop(); // all points processed
        } else {
            curr++;
            fixLineCoords();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Closed Polyline]

Comment: Thanks but it draws the point. I want to draw lines like my first example. Do you now how to make it?

Comment: It looks almost done, however I have an error `initialX = points[i][0];` in this part. where did you define the `i` ?

Comment: it should be `curr`

Comment: Thank you Alex, It is correct answer for this question. However I want to ask you more. If I need to draw from last item of array to first item of array. How to make that? As I need it.

Comment: Please check the update - added one more iteration and fixed calculation of point indexes using `% points.length` to avoid `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Thank you Alex, That's what I wanted to learn. Also, if I want to add another text file  which is like `141 430 177 452 205 463 232 468` . What should I do?

Comment: There are different approaches, if you need to add only 1 file, you can use another variable `String[] coords2=loadStrings("coordinates2.txt")` and then merge two arrays or possibly parameterize existing functionality to work with a single array of coordinates.  Or it is possible to add another dimension for file - so coordinates array becomes 2D and points - 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly I use array and fetch all line of my text file into array and then access them from index. sample code is here. further if you have problem in drawing of code you can text me.

```
/*Get Configration File*/
File fileSoucrce = new File (System.getenv("APPDATA")+"\\sapphire\\xmc.txt");
Scanner myReader;

this.console("Configration file exists.");

try {
        String[] fileText = new String[10];
        int i =0;
        myReader = new Scanner(fileSoucrce);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        fileText[i++]=myReader.nextLine();
        }
myReader.close();

ConnectString =fileText[0];
ConnectUSER       =fileText[1];
ConnectPassword       =fileText[2];
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Configration file not found at "+fileSoucrce.getAbsolutePath());
     Logger.getLogger(OracleCon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return;
}
```

Code is available in This InventoryMainPage.java
https://github.com/MuhammadFaisal1521/Java-Application-Inventory-Management-System-with-Oracle-Database/tree/master/src/Inventory